# Запрет обфускации члена класса

Tags: java, android, gradle, proguard

Имею класс

```
    public class MyClass{
    private Uri MyField;
    }
```

Задача

> Пройтись прогуардом по всем классам проекта(по умолчанию так и происходит),так же изменить имя у класса MyClass,но член MyField оставить без изменения.

Меняет все член в подрят в классе

```
-keep class com.test.test.MyClass {
    private android.net.Uri MyField;
}
```

Меняет только один нужный член

```
-keep class com.test.test.MyClass {
    private ** MyField;
}
```

Во всех вышеуказанных правилах не изменяется имя класса.Как мне изменить имя класса и один член в нем?

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял приведенное выше задание: нужно обфусцировать все, кро 1 поля в классе. Для этого допишите перед полем анатацию:

```
@SerializedName("MyField")
private Uri MyField;
```

А в proguard добавьте строку, разрешающую анатации:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Имя класса в таком варианте измениться, но имя поля останется преждним. Думаю, можно дописать такую анатацию и перед именем класса, чтобы ему имя не менялось.

Comment: А если в классе иные аннотации которые кипать не надо?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так то же работает

```
-keepclassmembernames class com.test.test.MyClass {
private android.net.Uri MyField;
}
```